# JMS queue consumer count is not increasing on JBoss EAP 7.1

Tags: jms, listener, consumer

JMS Message queue consumer count is not increasing  on JBoss EAP 7.1 even though message is being added to JMS Queue.  Consuming messages stopped working all of sudden.

We are using Spring JMS Listener and concurrency is set to 100.

[image: ConsumerCount zero]

**Config Class**

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableJms
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableCaching
@PropertySource("classpath:application-resources.properties")
@JBossLog
public class MyApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  private static Class<MyApp> applicationClass = MyApp.class;

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(applicationClass);
  }

  @Bean
  public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(
      ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MyAppJmsErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
    return factory;
  }

  @Service
  public class MyAppJmsErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleError(Throwable t) {
      log.error(t.getStackTrace());
    }
  }
}
```

**Listener Class:**

```java
@Component
public class MyListener {
  @Autowired
  TestService serviceInstance;

  @JmsListener(destination = TEST_QUEUE, concurrency = "100")
  public void onMessage(IncomingRequest request) {
    serviceInstance.callDB();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your Spring code/configuration.

Comment: Just added the code to the post. Consuming messages stopped working all of sudden. And consumer count is not increasing after that.